# Calling global function from constructor

Tags: c++, oop

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A;
struct B;

void g(A* a){ cout << "A";}
void g(B* b){ cout << "B";}

struct A{
    A(){ g(this); }
};

struct B : A{
    B(){}
};


int main() {
    B* b=new B();
    return 0;
}
```

in which the output is :

> A

Does this mean the type of `this` pointer passed to constructor `A()` is of type `A*`?

Comment: There are no virtuals in your code, so all typing is done purely statically.

Comment: @Angew: That has very little to do with this question, though.

Comment: @Angew if I add a virtual method in A, the output is still the same though

Comment: @KerrekSB I'd say it *does* have. Inside a member function of `A`, the static type of `this` cannot realistically be anything else than `A*`.

Comment: The comment about virtuals was meant to address the "binding steps" bit in the question: there is only static binding involved.

Comment: *In the constructor of A*, the dynamic type of `this` is A too.  Even if the object is eventually going to be a `B` object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

The thing is a `B` object is also a `A` object. While you are inside of the functions of `A` the class does not know if it is a `B` or not. So the `this`-ptr will be of type `A*`.

When you are calling functions inside of `B` it is `B*`.

Comment: so the binding is done statically. if I add a virtual method in A, would the binding still be static?

Comment: My answer has not really to do with static binding, But it would still be true then. Also for the virutal method issue: when you use inheritance you should always declare the destructor of the base class virtual.

Comment: @Loay: Search this site for "virtual functions" in "constructor"s if you're interested in how dynamic dispatch works in constructors. The type of `this` is always `A*`, no matter what you use the pointer for. But if you do use it to call a virtual function, then what's important is that *the most-derived object* is *also* the `A`-subobject while you're in its own constructor. It only becomes the complete object once *that* object's life has begun, which is only after one of *its* constructors has returned.

Comment: No, it isn't. Technically it's of type `A*`. This answer is wrong as it is.

Comment: @skypjack Yeah you are right. I assumed people realized I meant the type of the this-ptr not the type of this. Fixed that now.

Comment: _"While you are inside of the functions of A the class does not know if it is a B or not."_ More to the point, during `A`'s constructor, _it isn't a `B` yet anyway_.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in [[9.2.2.1/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.this#1) of the working draft (the this pointer):

> The type of **this** in a member function of a class X is X*.

Note that the constructor is a *special member function* and `A` is a subobject of `B`, thus the `this` pointer within the body of the member functions of `A` is of type `A*`, while it is of type `B*` within the member functions of `B`.
Note also that the `this` from `A` and the `this` from `B` can also have different values, that is they can point to different subobjects.
As an example:

```
#include<iostream>

struct A {
    A() { std::cout << this << std::endl; }
    int i{0};
};

struct B: A {
    B() { std::cout << this << std::endl; }
    virtual void f() {}
};

int main() {
    B b;
}
```

---

That said:

> Does this mean the type of **this** pointer passed to constructor `A()` is of type `A`?

No, it isn't. It's of type `A*`.

---

**EDIT**

Despite the OP edited the question and changed its meaning, I'd rather leave in this answer the quote from the original question.
A rollback would be a proper action for that edit maybe.
Anyway, the answer still applies.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is precisely what it means.

Comment: @skypjack Yes, that's what OP said.

Comment: @GillBates That's how the OP modified his question, not what he said. See my answer or the question history to see what he said.

Comment: @skypjack But now it's modified so you can remove the comment : ^)

Comment: @GillBates Actually he modified the question and now it's a completely different one, so the OP should rather rollback the edit.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13588553)

Comment: @BWA: This is literally the answer to the question. Pay more attention when reviewing, please.

Comment: @skypjack I edited the question for future references. The intention of the question isn't about whether the type is a pointer or a non-pointer, it's about the class type.